# Conseguir la lista de renglones los cuales cierta columna se repiten valores

Tags: sql-server, sql, group-by

Dispensen la redacción de la pregunta, espero con el ejemplo explicarme mejor.

Tengo la siguiente tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito conseguir la informacion de cuales idMono su columna Numero no cambia, en este casi seria el idMono 1 y 3.

A su vez tambien necesito la informacion de cuales idMono SI cambia su columna Numero, que en este caso seria idMono 2 y 4.

Espero haberme explicado bien. 
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes aplicarle group by a los campos que necesitas, esto para agrupar los valores repetidos

ejemplo:

```
SELECT idMono,Numero,Columna1,Columna2,Columna3 FROM Tabla GROUP BY idMono,Numero,Columna1,Columna2,Columna3
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea es obtener los `idMono` donde la cantidad de `numero` distintos sea igual a 1, es decir que no cambien.

```
select idMono
       from tabla
       group by idMono
       having count(distinct numero) = 1
```

El filtro en este caso es a nivel del `group by` mediante la cláusula `having`